# Captured image using RaspiCam got crop

Tags: raspbian, camera

I am working on a project using the Raspberry Pi model B and the Raspberry Pi CSI camera module (RaspiCam).

The problem is, captured image area when I'm using raspicam_test which in the raspicam library version 0.1.1 is different than when I'm using raspistill command. The captured image from raspicam_test is got crop and resized. Any idea how to solve this?

Here is the example of captured images

[image]

and this one is when im using raspistill command [image]

Comment: Can you include the command lines you're using for each?

Answer (score 0):

To crop the image in picamera use **camera.resolution = (310,200)**

Try this Code:

```
from time import sleep
import picamera

camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()

#Normal Size of Image
#camera.resolution = (1280,640)

# Cropped Image 
camera.resolution = (310,200)

sleep(2)
camera.capture('image_test.jpg')
camera.stop_preview
camera.close()
```

Hope this will help. Cheers!